# Make SQL Server connection work on any computer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to make program by using VB-VS2010 and SQL Server 2008. I want to make the SQL Server connection work on any computer which the user puts his information:

1. Server Name:
2. Database Name:
3. User
4. Password

and the program should read this information and connect to SQL Server with this information, even if the computer is different

And when the program reads there are a connection the user can import data into database. Table in his database

I created a sample of the program but it works on my PC only due to the

```
mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=SRO_VT_ACCOUNT;user id=sa;password=123"
```

So the program read this code... now I need to delete this and make sql connection by the user info [Like That Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQz3f.png)

My sample program is:

[form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oktwl.png)

Form 1 Code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Public mysqlconn As SqlConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mysqlconn = New SqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=SRO_VT_ACCOUNT;user id=sa;password=123"

        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("There are a connection")
            Form2.Show()
            mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exceptiona
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mysqlconn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

My Form2 Code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form2
    Public mysqlconn As SqlConnection
    Public command As SqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mysqlconn = New SqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=SRO_VT_ACCOUNT;user id=sa;password=123"
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into TB_User (StrUserID,password)  Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
            command = New SqlCommand(Query, mysqlconn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
            mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: There is no reason for global Connection and Command objects since you create `New` ones in those methods.  the only thing you save is `Dim`, but theu also ought to be disposed of

Comment: Hmmmmm i don't UnderStand You Tell me What Should Can i do to make Connection work in any pc Tut video or post or any somthing else.

Comment: You **urgently** need to learn the absolute basics of ADO.NET - try to find tutorials like [this ADO.NET tutorial here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) until you understand what a connection, a connection string etc. is ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions isn't super clear, but it seems like you just want the user to build the connection string based on the inputs on your form.

doing

```
mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=SRO_VT_ACCOUNT;user id=sa;password=123"
```

is only going to work for you because you're not even looking at the form values. I'm going to assume your "Server Name" textbox is "txtServerName". You'd need to do something like this

```
mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + txtServerName.Text + "; initial catalog=SRO_VT_ACCOUNT;user id=sa;password=123"
```

And you'd need to do the same for the initial catalog, user id, and password.

Comment: Thnx very much it worked with me now justin packwood

Answer (score 3):

Put you connection string to [the config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
... other settings
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=userid;Password=userpassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
  ... other settings
</configuration>
```

Then you should do something like this in your code:

```
Private Shared Function GetConnectionStringByProvider( _
ByVal providerName As String) As String

'Return Nothing on failure.
Dim returnValue As String = Nothing

' Get the collection of connection strings.
 Dim settings As ConnectionStringSettingsCollection = _
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

  '  Walk through the collection and return the first 
  ' connection string matching the providerName.
  If Not settings Is Nothing Then
      For Each cs As ConnectionStringSettings In settings
          If cs.ProviderName = providerName Then
              returnValue = cs.ConnectionString
              Exit For
          End If
      Next
  End If

   Return returnValue
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mysqlconn = New SqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = GettConnectionStringByProvider("MyConnectionString")

    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("There are a connection")
        Form2.Show()
        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exceptiona
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What are You Mean About [Put you connection string to the config file.] iam new about coding,Excusme can You Explain More..

Comment: Click the link in the first line of my answer. You should parametrize this setting.

Comment: i Don't UnderStand Any Thing :(..... This Code: >><?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
... other settings
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=userid;Password=userpassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
  ... other settings
</configuration> where Should i Paste it? in form or MOdule or class or what? sorry for the more questions But i need to Understand...